# JSP Special Character Validation not working

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have written a code for validation of the JSp page. But Special character validation is  not working. Can someone please tell me the reason. If my method is wrong please notify me with correct one.

**JSP Code**

```
<%-- 
    Document   : LapsePeriodicFeedBack
    Created on : Dec 7, 2012, 2:50:28 PM
    Author     : Admin
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@page import="PeriodicFeedBack.PeriodicType"%>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>LapsePeriodicList</title>
        <style>

        body {
            font: 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            background-color:#E4Eff4;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 10px;
        }
        </style>
        <script>
            function validateForm(){
                var iChars = "!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?";
                var selectindex=document.forms["lapse"]["periodmenu"].selectedIndex;
                var whitespace = /\w+/g;
                var x= document.forms["lapse"]["lapsedays"].value;
                var textlength=document.forms["lapse"]["lapsedays"].length;
                if(x==""){
                    alert("Days Cant Be Empty");
                    return false;
                }
                if(!whitespace.test(x)){
                    alert("White Spaces are not Allowed");
                    return false;
                }
                if(selectindex==0){

                    alert("Please select Days from menu");
                }
                if(isNaN(x)){
                    alert("Only Numbers Allowed");
                    return false;
                }

        if(x.indexOf(iChars) != -1) {
        alert ("The box has special characters. \nThese are not allowed.\n");
        return false;
   }

 }




        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form  method="post" name="lapse" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="LapsePeriodicFbUpdate">
            <table width="450px" border="1" align="center" style='border-collapse: collapse;font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;' bordercolor='#000000'>

                <tr  style="color:'#ffffff';background-color:#CA1619;background-repeat:repeat-x;font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="4" align="center">
               <font color="#ffffff" > <b>Periodic Feedback List</b></font></td></tr>
                <tr >
                    <td align="center">
                    Periodic Feedback Days</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <select id="periodmenu" STYLE="width: 150px" name="periodmenu">
                            <option>Select</option>
                            <%
        PeriodicType p = new PeriodicType();
        ArrayList periodicList = p.getPeriodicType();
        for (int i = 0; i < periodicList.size(); i++) {%>
        <option value="<%=periodicList.get(i)%>">

                                <% out.println(periodicList.get(i));
        }%>
                            </option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                    Lapse Days &nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="center">
                     <input id="lapsedays" name="lapsedays" onkeyup="nospaces(this)" style="width:145px;" type="text" />
                    </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                         <td align="right" colspan="2"><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
                     </tr>


            </table>
        </form>
        <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if i add special character is shows white space not allowed alert,what can i do should i change whitespace validation or something is wrong in special characters validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `x.indexOf(iChars)` matches `x` against the FULL `iChars` string.

You could use a regex search as in:

```
var iChars = "[!@#$%^&*()+=\\-\\[\\]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?]{1}";
....
if(x.search(iChars) != -1)
....
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841004/how-to-block-special-characters-in-jsp Carlo Pellegrini please help for this question